# KeyValue <-> ValueKey - Dictionary access memory efficient

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following classes

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo1
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo2
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class BaseFoo
{

}

public class Bar
{

}
```

Currently I have HashSets of about 100.000 entries of Foo, Foo1, Foo2

```
public HashSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
public HashSet<Foo1> Foo1s { get; set; }
public HashSet<Foo1> Foo2s { get; set; }
```

This works great with checks if a Foo already exists and all other benefits that come with an HashSet.

Now my requirement would be to also check if there is a Foo with a specific Bar in the list and return it.

Currently I am doing as this:

```
public Foo GetFooByBar(Bar bar)
{
    return Foos.FirstOrDefault(x => object.ReferenceEquals(x.Bar, Bar));
}
public Foo GetFoo1ByBar(Bar bar)
{
    return Foo1s.FirstOrDefault(x => object.ReferenceEquals(x.Bar, Bar));
}
public Foo GetFoo2ByBar(Bar bar)
{
    return Foo2s.FirstOrDefault(x => object.ReferenceEquals(x.Bar, Bar));
}
```

Sadly this piece of code is rather slow, since it can happen in my application that I need to check for 100.000 or more (if there are new Foos to be created) Bars if they are inside the Foos collection.

So the GetFooByBar method gets executed rather often and since I am traversing the whole list every time its not really fast.

I thought about implementing an additional dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<Bar, Foo> Foo_Bars { get; set; }
Dictionary<Bar, Foo> Foo1_Bars { get; set; }
Dictionary<Bar, Foo> Foo2_Bars { get; set; }
```

and than re-write my GetFooByBar method like this:

```
public Foo GetFooByBar(Bar bar)
{
    Foo foo;
    Foo_Bars.TryGetValue(bar, out foo)
    return foo;
}
public Foo GetFoo1ByBar(Bar bar)
{
    Foo foo;
    Foo1_Bars.TryGetValue(bar, out foo)
    return foo;
}
public Foo GetFoo1ByBar(Bar bar)
{
    Foo foo;
    Foo2_Bars.TryGetValue(bar, out foo)
    return foo;
}
```

With this I am afraid about memory issues since I will than have 1 HashSet and 1 Dictionary for each of my classes around 90 of them, not all of those 90 can have 100.000 entries it varies highly but it can be easily around 5.000.000 entries in total. (so approximately 55.000 per class)

I also thought about just doing 1 Dictionary containing the base class of Foo, instead of doing 1 additional dictionary for each class:

```
Dictionary<Bar, BaseFoo> Bars { get; set; }
```

With the GetFooByBar method like this:

```
public T GetFooByBar(Bar bar) where T : BaseFoo
{
    BaseFoo baseFoo;
    Bars.TryGetValue(bar, out baseFoo)
    return (T)baseFoo;        
}
```

But with this I would end up with 1 Dictionary with 5.000.000 entries.

Do you guys have a different idea, if my ways are the only possible ones which is the better one taking into account memory and performance?!?

Comment: 5.000.000 items seems not too much in terms of memory. I suppose your Foos and Bars are, classes (not structs), so only reference to them will be stored in dictionaries\hashsets. Reference is basically a pointer, so on 64bit machine 5.000.000 references is just around 38 MB. Depending on environment maybe not something to worry about.

Comment: SortedList<TKey,TValue> would be a bit slower than the Dictionary ( `O(log(n))` vs `O(1)` which shouldn't make such a big difference with 5M entries, and won't have huge memory footprint. Even with a dictionary it should be just fine

Comment: You can use TPL to accomplish parallel execution. You can create a `Task<Bar>` for each foo and then use `Task.WaitAny` to wait on the first successful operation.

Comment: it looks like you are designing a database, so why not use a database?

Comment: Trading memory for speed is a standard programming concern.  If the code is too slow then there is very little reason to fret about it, you have no choice and 16 gigabytes of RAM is dirt-cheap today.  You are not close yet to using it.